# Cannot install Ultralytics using pip in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, pip, pythonanywhere

I was trying to install the module `ultralytics` (for YOLOv8) in the bash of hosting service PythonAnywhere

I tried:

`pip  install ultralytics`

But get:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ultralytics (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for ultralytics

I can install using the same method in my local machine , but having trouble in PythonAnywhere

I upgraded pip, but no difference

Why is this happening?

Comment: What version of `python` are you running? `ultralytics` requires a `python` version `>=3.7`

Comment: To add to the above -- if you run `pip --version`, at the end of the output you'll see the version of Python that it's configured to use (eg. something like `python 3.7`).  PythonAnywhere has various versions of Python installed (based on your system image, which you can see on the "Account" page; mappings from system images to available Python versions are at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ChangingSystemImage), and each has its associated `pip` command, for example `pip3.7` for Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a newer version of Python with version >= 3.7

Then run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade your pip and install ultralytics again.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?